# Proc Tabulate - Show Transposed Class Variable In Dataset

Tags: sas, proc, enterprise-guide

I Hope someone can help - I have just started using Enterprise guide. I have created a PROC TABULATE summary table using the wizard and I want to output the results to a SAS dataset, however when I do one of the class variables (month) is not transposed as it is in the summary output table - is there away to tell the wizard to do this or adjust the code?

Eg

.............Month1 Month2 Month3 Month3

Group1
Group2
Group3
Group4

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Sadly no. The displayed results table produced does not match the output table.  You will need to create different code, depending on your calculations proc means or summary may be more efficient that using proc tabulate.

Comment: Many thanks - ahhh ok I may look into a way around it